# Mostrar pagina .php en la misma vista y en diferente <div>

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema al querer cargar una pagina dentro de un div, tengo actualmente un menu en arbol, el cual tiene submenús; cada uno tiene un href='' el cual va a un controlador y ese controlador a una vista, ejemplo

http://localhost/bedsheet/menu

Muestra lo que es el menú como tal.

[image: Menú]

Lo máximo que he hecho es esto y no funciona es con JQUERY

```
<div class="row" id="header">
<div class="col-3" style="background-color:#fffded;">
    <div class="container">

            <ol class='tree'><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Módulo Financiero</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/>
            <ol class='tree'><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='welcome' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Cargue Excel</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li></ol></li><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Módulo Recursos</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/>
            <ol class='tree'><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='#' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Empresas</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='#' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Personas</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='#' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Empleados</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='#' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Situación</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li></ol></li><li><label for='subfolder2'><a href='#' class='cargar' name='objeto'>Módulo Datos</a></label> <input type='checkbox' name='subfolder2'/></li></ol>        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-9" style="background-color:#FFFF;" id="objeto">

</div>

<script>
    $("a.cargar").live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var div = "#"+$(this).attr("name");
        $(div).append(this);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Y me sale el nombre más no la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien me ayuda, estoy muy agradecido, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si estas usando JQuery, no has pensado en usar [JSTree](https://www.jstree.com/), de no querer usarlo, podrias compartir tu css o todo lo que involucre tu problema para poder replicar el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo este código, espero te sirva.

Tienes la función "Obtener_Objeto" y "Peticion", esto es para jalar el código:

```
function obtener_objeto()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (windows.ActiveXObject)
    {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("No soporta");
    }
}
var solicitud=obtener_objeto(); 

function peticion()
{

    if (solicitud.readyState==0 || solicitud.readyState==4)
    {
    solicitud.open("GET","TuArchivo.html",true);
    solicitud.onreadystatechange=mostrar;
    solicitud.send(null);
    }
}
```

En "TuArchivo.html" vas a poner el archivo que quieres que se muestre al dar clic.

En la función "Mostrar" vas a poner en donde quieres que aparezca.

```
function mostrar()
{
    if (solicitud.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML=solicitud.responseText;
    }
}
```

Donde dice "contenido" es el ID del `span` donde quieres que se muestre.

Ahora, en tu `href` solo pones el nombre del método donde haces la petición y te lo va a mostrar sin redireccionar la pagina:

```
<li><a href="javascript:peticion();">Productos</a></li>
```