# Cargar pagina php en un modal

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

tengo una pagina php donde muestro el contenido de una carpeta, el problema que tengo es que me gustaría ver esa pagina dentro de un modal, pero cuando ejecuto el cogido me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si abro la pagina desde el navegador directamente, funciona bien, pero el problema es cuando la quiero ver en el modal.

esta de aquí es mi pagina php donde mustro el contenido de la carpeta.

explorador.php

```
 <?php
$subdirectorio='31596234984';
$directorio = opendir(storage_path('app/Documentos/'.$subdirectorio.'/')); //ruta actual
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{
    if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
    {
        //echo "[".$archivo . "]<br />"; //de ser un directorio lo envolvemos entre corchetes
    }
    else
    {
        echo $archivo;
    }

}
```

?>

y esta de acá es mi pagina desde donde quiero llamar a la pagina explorador.php

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.5.1.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
  
       <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formulario" method="Post" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="d-inline">
        <input type="button" id="button1" name="enviar" value="Eliminar" class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm btn-block"><br>
     </form>
     <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">

         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div id="capa">Div que se actualiza</div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
            
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button1").click(function(event) {
            $("#capa").load("../resources/views/app/explorador.blade.php");
        });
    });         
</script>  
</html>
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: No entendí muy bien, pero puedes hacer una petición GET con ajax o fetch y cargar el resultado en el modal.

Comment: Ya vi tu código. Estás llamando una plantilla de blade, y necesitas hacer el call a la ruta que contiene esa plantilla.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema, me sirvio la solución de este caso
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231691/mostrar-pagina-php-en-la-misma-vista-y-en-diferente-div)

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Entonces no pongo nada y la dejo como abierta?